# Python Pandas Column Value with Threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframe:

```
Package   Order   Threshold
3         2       0.6
4         0       0.8
5         1       1.2
6         2       1.2
6         4       1.5
```

> If my "Order" values greater than "Threshold" it should be updated as
>   "Package" Values.
>
> If my "Order" values lower than "Threshold" it should be updated as "0 (zero)".

Desired output is;

```
Package   Order   Threshold
3         3       0.6
4         0       0.8
5         0       1.2
6         6       1.2
6         6       1.5
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: Since 2>0.6, shouldn't the first line go to 3 3 0.6 ?

Comment: Use `df['Order'] = np.where(df['Order'].gt(df['Threshold']), df['Package'], 0)`